# Angular 2 http api invocation fails due underscore in url

Tags: angular, couchdb

When trying to invoke CouchDB view GET API (URL :
http://localhost:5984/testdb/_design/tcViews/_view/get_tc_products?group=true )
getting **404** status with error as  "**Collection '_design' not found**".

I am able to get results from couchDB (v1.6.1) when the same URL is invoked via PostMan/SoapUI . There is no error logged in CouchDB logger.

I tried encoding '_' character in URL however got the same error.

I tried searching around this issue but no luck so far ..

Any suggestion please ..

Below is my service class -

```
export class TestcasesService {
    private dbApiHostPort:string ;
    private dbName:string;
    private productByTcApiUrl:string;
    private productByTcAPIQueryUrl:string;


    constructor(private http: Http,
                @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config:Config) { 
       this.dbApiHostPort  = config.couchDbHostPort;
       this.dbName =  config.couchDbDBName;
       this.productByTcApiUrl = config.couchDbGetTcProductUrl;
           this.productByTcAPIQueryUrl='http://localhost:5984/testdb/_design/tcViews/_view/get_tc_products?group=true';
    }

    getProductsForTcs(): Observable<ProductResults> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(this.productByTcAPIQueryUrl,options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    private extractData(res: Response) {
         let body = res.json();
         return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }


}
```

This is how it's used in one of the component -

```
export class TestcasesFilterComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    public selectedProduct:ProductResult;
    public errorMessage:any ;

    public disabled:boolean = false;
    public status:{isopen:boolean} = {isopen: true};
    public items:ProductResults ;

    constructor(private testcasesService: TestcasesService,
        private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     let defaultProduct:ProductResult = new ProductResult();
     defaultProduct.key ="Select Product";
     this.selectedProduct = defaultProduct;
      this.testcasesService.getProductsForTcs().subscribe(
                     products => this.items = products,
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }
    onProductSelect(productResult:ProductResult){
     this.selectedProduct =  productResult;
    }
}
```

And this is what i get in Chrome console -

[error in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foJKx.jpg)

Solution -
After banging my head for few days , i realized that i had a mistake in my main.ts . It was configured to use InMemoryBackend service .

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS,
    provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: InMemoryBackendService }), // in-mem server
    provide(SEED_DATA, { useClass: InMemoryDataService })     // in-mem server data ]);
```

Commenting InMemory service resolved the issue -

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS,
   // provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: InMemoryBackendService }), // in-mem server
   // provide(SEED_DATA, { useClass: InMemoryDataService })     // in-mem server data
]);
```

Comment: Have you compared requests using chrome developer tools?

Comment: There's no request body as it's GET API (http method = GET ) . I did verified that  request url/headers are as per expectation however still issue persist.